# Why does an angular function in the view keep firing?

Tags: angularjs

How do I stop this, why does it happen or am I implementing this incorrectly?

For example:

```
  $scope.testFunction = function (x) {
    console.log(x)
  }

<div ng-bind="testFunction(5)">test</div>
```

- The console keeps logging 5 repeatedly.

Comment: Probably multiple digests... What is it, exactly, that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I"m more trying to understand why this happens and is that expected behavior.

Comment: yes, this is the expected behaviour... if you don't want it to fire multiple times, consider using `one-time binding` syntax

Comment: Thanks @pwolaq.  Will the view update if the model updates if I use one-time binding?

Comment: no, as the name says, it removes watcher after value is defined

Comment: @pwolaq Thank you.